# Can I remove "Linux/Ebury Operation Windigo" without wiping the entire drive?

Tags: osx, malware, chkrootkit

I used `chkrootkit`, which told me that I had "Linux/Ebury Operation Windigo" installed, I doubled checked by running `ssh -G` which printed out usage, without "illegal option". I removed all ssh files and reinstalled it, but when I ran `ssh -G` again I still had it, also detected by `chkrootkit`.

Can you remove this without wiping the entire drive? Are there any files I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way to find out if you are actually infected. From what I have read, these two are the tried and true methods as chkrootkit only returns suspicion about being infected, not a guarantee. If you run the following two commands and nothing comes back, I would say it's a false positive.

This one searches for it's network socket

```
netstat -nap | grep "@/proc/udevd"
```

This one searches for the module it installs

```
find /lib* -type f -name libns2.so
```

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is an old thread, but I'm adding additional information for clarity.)

If you are actually infected, pretty much the only reliable solution is to wipe and reinstall. However, it is well established that as of the moment, chrootkit frequently identifies a false positive for Windigo.

In the whitepaper on Windigo that ESET published, it details another method of checking for windigo by looking at shared memory segments.

https://www.welivesecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/operation_windigo.pdf

Essentially, you need to run:

```
sudo ipcs -m
```

and look for any entries that have permissions greater than 600 or that use a relatively large amount of memory. If there aren't any, then you are likely clean.

If there are, then note the segment id ( shmid ) and run:

```
sudo ipcs -m -p
```

get the process id ( pid ) and you can find out what the process is with:

```
sudo ps aux | grep <pid>
```

If you don't recognize the process then do some additional research on it to determine whether it is a potential threat. There is a good technical analysis including SHA-1 hashes of the infection at https://www.welivesecurity.com/2014/02/21/an-in-depth-analysis-of-linuxebury/ that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `ssh -G` check is outdated.  I just checked on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04, and it does not return an "unknown" or "illegal" even though I'm fairly sure both systems are clean.

So on more modern systems, the `ssh -G` check seems to always come up with a false positive.